# Starting google-chrome via Selenium on headless debian system

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-rc, headless, xvfb, robotframework

I'm trying to start the google-chrome browser in disabled web security mode. The selenium log says:

```
15:36:33.526 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*googlechrome, http://www.myurl.de, , commandLineFlags=--disable-web-security] on session null
```

Anyways, it just hangs after

```
15:36:33.600 INFO - Launching Google Chrome...
```

Here's the stack trace:

`16:36:44.605 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: timed out waiting for window 'null' to appear at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:564) at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:521) at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:374) at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:125) at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:87) at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:785) at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:422) at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:393) at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:146) at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530) at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482) at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909) at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820) at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986) at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837) at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243) at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357) at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)`

Selenium is started by robotframework by the robotframework-maven-plugin. Also xvfb is started by the maven build script to simulate a display. But the startup configuration does not seem to be the problem. Everything starts fine, just the browser won't get up.

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Which versions of RF SeleniumLibrary and google-chrome are you running?

Comment: Is the DISPLAY environment variable set ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user account that is launching the browser has a home directory.  Otherwise the browser profile creation will fail.